# How does Facebook implement it's "see more" feature on post text content.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to cut off post text content at either 6 lines or by a certain number of word characters. Fortunately, after using [this JQuery plugin](http://rockycode.com/blog/jquery-plugin-readmore/), I have managed to cut off post text content at a certain number of word characters.

What is remaining is to cut off post text content at 6 lines. It's unfortunate that [this JQuery plugin](http://rockycode.com/blog/jquery-plugin-readmore/) can't do it. I need anyone's help on this. This image below illustrates what I want to implement.

[image: Facebook "see more" style]

Comment: have you looked substr_len: option of plugin..?

Comment: @STFU_NC Do you mean you want to cut off the text after a certain amount of lines, not after a certain number of characters?

Comment: I want to cut off post text content at either 6 lines or by a certain number of word characters.

Answer (score 0):

1. 2 divs for every post
2. hide second div by default
3. check if the content has limited data, then set to div1 one only
4. if content has data more than your char limit, set limited data in to div1, complete data in div2 and also add a action link ("see more") in div 1
5. on click of link in div1 show the div2

This div2 doesnt have to be added in every post, you can also add it dynamically with `display="none"`.

Comment: Also note that there's one space after punctuation, but none before (`...every post, you can...`, *not* `...every post , you can...`)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the div's `height: 6em`, then restore it to `height: auto` when the "Read more" link is clicked. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jv7Dj/1/.